# Heroku add custom godaddy domain not working

Tags: heroku, dns, laravel-5.4

I have a heroku app and also have bought a custom domain for it from Go Daddy.I have added custom domain to my heroku app like this from my project folder root:

```
heroku domains:add www.noujontro.com
```

After this,I go to my Go daddy DNS Management section and edit it like this:

[image: Go Daddy DNS Section]

I also have done the forwarding configuration Like this:

[image: DNS Forwarding]

But now when I go to www.noujontro.com,it shows me this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your `CNAME` by running `heroku domains -a your_app_name`. You may need to change it.

[Source](https://kb.heroku.com/what-is-the-correct-dns-cname-target-for-my-custom-domains): from second to the last topic

Comment: I have checked my CNAME target by running this command.It's the same target I have been using.I think the problem is in host.Should it be http instead of www?